# Mail merge - Change data in source from merged document

Tags: microsoft-excel, email, microsoft-word, mail-merge

I have an excel file with thousands of records. I want to mail merge and build a directory which I have done.

The problem is when directory was built I noticed that there were some errors. I want to correct errors in mail merged document and want that to be changed in the source document (excel file) as well.

I know there are two methods of doing this - one is to manually edit in data source before mail merge and other is to edit records when choosing a data source but I want to do the changes from the compiled mail merged file as its much easier to spot errors.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You want to do something against the concept of mail merge. 
Spot the errors, correct the excel file and re-generate after every 10 minutes you do this.

Comment: Where is the **10 minute** mark coming from?